# AsyncTask pass Generic Type to inner interface result handler

Tags: java, android

How can I use a variable Type parameter within a subclass of AsyncTask (which I intend to subclass again) where the Type parameter is used in a static context?

For example:

```
public abstract class ListAsyncTask<Identifier,ListType> extends AbsAsyncTask<Identifier, List<ListType>> {
protected final String TAG = Utils.generateTag(this.getClass());
ResultListener listener;

WebProxy proxy;
String server;

public interface ResultListener {
    void handleAsyncResult(List<?> result);
}
```

I'm returning results of the AsyncTask using the ResultListener and I would like to use the Type variable "ListType" within ResultListener's interface method signature, but I can't reference it due to the interface's static context as an inner interface.

I suppose I could define the interface outside of the AsyncTask class, but the idea was to have them tightly joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 choices.

(1) Make the interface generic:

```
public interface ResultListener<ListType> {
    void handleAsyncResult(List<ListType> result);
}
```

(2) Use an (inner) abstract class rather than an interface:

```
public abstract class ResultListener {
    void handleAsyncResult(List<ListType> result);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I went with option 1), which I didn't even realize was a possibility.  Thanks for opening my eyes, Paul.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.